# How do you calculate the magnitude of the light waves emitted from an LED?

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation

Question is in the title.  My goal is to see if this is enough to make an interferometer using a surface-mount photodetector.

Comment: Look at the datasheet. It will tell you the typical output power at the recommended operating current. However, the light from an LED is generally not coherent enough to use in an interferometer.

Comment: It only takes one photon to get an interference pattern.  What is the detector you plan to use?  That will help define the minimum power you need.

Comment: basic op amp voltage amplifier

Comment: If not interferometer, at least distance approximation using the inverse square law

Comment: If you can make the question more clear about what you're actually trying to do, it might get better answers on [electronics stackexchange](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Or just google "LED proximity sensor".

Comment: An LED won't make a nice interference pattern for you. You will need a laser diode for that. Make sure it's a single mode laser and get your hands on some spectral information before you commit to a part. Better still, get a cheap HeNe laser. The line width of a laser is controlled by the Q of the optical resonator and that should be many times higher for a 4" or so gas laser than a tiny laser diode. Coherence lengths for a laser diode are in the mm range, for a multimode gas laser in the 20cm range. If you can get the gas laser to give you single mode, then you have 50m coherence length!

Comment: And make sure you understand the difference between spatial coherence (one can make candle light spatially coherent with ease) and temporal coherence.